# extremely confused about how this "oop under-the-hood" example of a counter works

Tags: oop, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

here's the `make-counter` procedure and calls to it

```
(define make-counter
    (let ((glob 0))
        (lambda ()
            (let ((loc 0))
                (lambda ()
                    (set! loc (+ loc 1))
                    (set! glob (+ glob 1))
                    (list loc glob))))))

> (define counter1 (make-counter))
 counter1

> (define counter2 (make-counter))
 counter2

> (counter1)
(1 1)

> (counter1)
(2 2)

> (counter2)
(1 3)

> (counter1)
(3 4)
```

i can't understand why does `glob` behaves as a class variable, while `loc` behaves as an instance variable.

Comment: I had to read "oop counter example" twice :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be easiest to consider when each part of the code is run.  You evaluate

```
(define make-counter (let ((0 glob)) ...))
```

just once, so the **let** is evaluated just once.  That means that there's only *one* binding, and its value is shared by everything within the body of the **let**.  Now, what's in body of the **let**?  It's a lambda function, which becomes the value of **make-counter**:

```
(lambda ()          ; this function is the value of make-counter

  (let ((loc 0))    ; so this stuff gets execute *each time* that
    (lambda ()      ; make-counter is called
      ...           ;
      )))           ;
```

Now, every time you *call* **make-counter**, you evaluate **(let ((loc 0)) (lambda () …))**, which creates a new binding and returns a lambda function that has access to it (as well as to the global binding from outside.

So each result from calling **make-counter** has access to the *single* binding of **glob**, as well as to access to a per-result binding of **loc**.

Answer (score 2):

Let us examine the program:

```
(define make-counter
  (let ((g 0))
    (lambda ()
      (let ((l 0))
        (lambda ()
          (set! l (+ l 1))
          (set! g (+ g 1))
          (list l g))))))
```

The program illustrates how an abstraction (`lambda`-expression) creates
a closure that contains references to the free variables.

It would be helpful to see and inspect the free variables explicitly,
so let's pretend we want to run the program above in a language
that doesn't support `lambda`. In other words, let try to rewrite
the program into one that uses simpler constructs.

The first is to get rid of assignments. Let's allocate a box
(think vector of length one) that can hold one value.
An assignment can then change the value that box holds using set-box!.

```
; Assignment conversion: Replace assignable variables with boxes.
; The variables l and g are both assigned to

 (define make-counter
   (let ((g (box 0)))
     (lambda ()
       (let ((l (box 0)))
         (lambda ()
           (set-box! l (+ (unbox l) 1))
           (set-box! g (+ (unbox g) 1))
           (list (unbox l) (unbox g)))))))
```

This program is equivalent to the original (try it!).

The next step is to annotate each lambda with its free variables:

```
(define make-counter
  (let ((g (box 0)))
    (lambda ()           ; g is free in lambda1
      (let ((l (box 0)))
        (lambda ()       ; g and l are free lambda2
          (set-box! l (+ (unbox l) 1))
          (set-box! g (+ (unbox g) 1))
          (list (unbox l) (unbox g)))))))
```

Now we are ready to replace `lambda` with explicit closures.
A closure holds
   i) a function with no free variables 
  ii) values of the free variable at the time the closure was created

We will use a vector to store i) and ii).

```
(define (make-closure code . free-variables)
  (apply vector code free-variables))
```

We can get the function with no free variables like this:

```
(define (closure-code closure)
  (vector-ref closure 0))
```

And we can the i'th free variable like this:

```
(define (closure-ref closure i)
  (vector-ref closure (+ i 1)))
```

To apply a closure one calls the function with no free variables (code)
with both the closure (which code will need to find the values of the 
free variables) and the actual arguments.

```
(define (apply-closure closure . args)
  (apply (closure-code closure) closure args))
```

Here are the code corresponding to the lambda1

```
(define (lambda1 cl) ; cl = (vector lambda1 g)
  (let ((g (closure-ref cl 0))) ; g is the first free variable of lambda1
    (let ((l (box 0)))
      (make-closure lambda2 g l))))
```

Since lambda1 was a function of no arguments, the only input is the closure.
The first thing it does is to retrieve the free value g.

Note that lambda1 returns a closure: (make-closure lambda2 g l)
Here we see that when the closure for lambda2 is made the values of g and l
are preserved.

Now lambda2:

```
(define (lambda2 cl) ; cl = (vector lambda2 g l)
  (let ((g (closure-ref cl 0))
        (l (closure-ref cl 1)))
    (set-box! l (+ (unbox l) 1))
    (set-box! g (+ (unbox g) 1))
    (list (unbox l) (unbox g))))
```

Finally make-counter which simply makes a lambda1-closure:

```
(define make-counter (make-closure lambda1 (box 0)))
```

We are now ready to see our program in action:

```
(define counter1 (apply-closure make-counter))
counter1
(define counter2 (apply-closure make-counter))
counter2

(apply-closure counter1)
(apply-closure counter1)
(apply-closure counter2)
(apply-closure counter1)
```

The output is:

```
'#(#<procedure:lambda2> #&0 #&0)
'#(#<procedure:lambda2> #&0 #&0)
'(1 1)
'(2 2)
'(1 3)
'(3 4)
```

This means out program works in the same way as the original.
Now however we can examine the free variables of the two counters:

```
> counter1
'#(#<procedure:lambda2> #&4 #&3)
> counter2
'#(#<procedure:lambda2> #&4 #&1)
```

We can check that the two counters share the same g:

```
> (eq? (closure-ref counter1 0)
       (closure-ref counter2 0))
#t
```

We can also check that they have two different boxes containing l.

```
> (eq? (closure-ref counter1 1)
   (closure-ref counter2 1))

#f
```

Comment: This is similar to how some compilers treat closures. Chez at least. Does racket do this as well?

Comment: Yes. Assignment conversion followed by closure conversion is very common among Scheme compilers. Dybvig figured out that assignment conversion allows the use of a stack based model even in the presence of first class continuations. ( https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/3imp.pdf )